# Python translation of C code not working

Tags: python, c, algorithm, divide-and-conquer

I want to find the maximum element in an array in `O(log N)` time using divide and conquer. I found a working code at [planet-source-code](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=12673&lngWId=3). I translated it into Python as follows:

```
def largest(arr,i,j):
    global max1
    global max2
    if i == j:
        max1 = arr[i]
    else:
        if i == j-1:
           max1 = arr[i] if arr[i] > arr[j] else arr[j]
        else:
              mid = (i+j)/2
              largest(arr,i,mid)
              max2 = max1
              largest(arr,mid+1,j)
              if max2 > max1:
             max1 = max2
```

When I use an array `[98,5,4,3,2,76,78,92]`, and call the code as

```
max1 = arr[0]
largest(arr,1,8)
```

I am getting a out-of-bound list index error. However the C code returns the correct result 98. Can anyone spot what error am I doing?

Comment: You're not using the exact same code. The C code has 3 If statement.

Comment: Please check your indentation

Comment: Also, that code does not find the min and max in O(lg n) time; in fact, that's impossible. It takes at least linear time, and a simple linear scan would probably be faster.

Comment: O(lg n) is only possible if the array is sorted and you use a binary search. Anyway, try calling `largest(0, 7)`... see if that works

Comment: You should be calling `largest(arr,0,7)` or maybe `largest(arr,1,7)`.

Comment: @IonutHulub: If the array is sorted, you can do it in O(1).

Comment: Straightforward application of the [master method](http://www.cs.ucdavis.edu/~gusfield/cs222f07/mastermethod.pdf) shows that the algorithm given in fact takes exactly linear time, so it is optimal, though still contrived.

Comment: every time you use global in python, a programmer dies

Comment: @IonutHulub maybe you were thinking of an array with a first ascending part, followed by a descending part. That's where you can find the max in O(log n), but not better (I'm not 100% sure of the very last assertion).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a general unsorted array, you can never find the `max` in anything less than O(n) time. The very trivial proof: if you do it in less than O(n) time, then for a sufficiently large array you don't have enough time to inspect every element. An adversary can therefore put the maximum value in an element you don't check, making your algorithm incorrect.

What the original code is good for is finding *both* the maximum and minimum simultaneously using fewer than 2n comparisons (as the naive implementation would do) -- it uses approximately 1.5n comparisons since it performs only one comparison when there are two elements. You derive no benefit from using it to only find the maximum: you'd be better off using `max(arr)` in Python instead (which would also be faster since it has no function call overhead).

The original code stores the values in `a[1]` through `a[n]`, which requires an array of size `n+1`. Therefore you should put a dummy element in the first position.

But, more problematically, your translation is incorrect. The original uses globals to effect a multiple value return (which is an incredibly hacky way to do it), and local variables to save the old globals. Since you make both `max1` and `max2` global, the function will not produce the right answer anyway.

The correct translation to Python would use a direct multiple value return with a tuple:

```
def minmax(arr, i, j):
    if i==j:
        return arr[i], arr[i]
    elif i==j-1:
        if arr[i] < arr[j]:
            return arr[i], arr[j]
        else:
            return arr[j], arr[i]
    else:
        mid = (i+j)//2
        min1, max1 = minmax(arr, i, mid)
        min2, max2 = minmax(arr, mid+1, j)
        if min2 < min1: min1 = min2
        if max2 > max1: max1 = max2
        return min1, max1
```

Comment: By they way, in python using `m, M = min(arr), max(arr)` will be (in the average case) faster than this algorithm for any real size array, since the two functions are written in C. Anything that uses python-level iteration should *at least* have a lower asymptotic complexity to be competitive and this is not possible.
[and, in general, sometimes not even a lower complexity is enough for real-world cases]

Comment: Yes, you are very correct. This code here should be treated only as a learning exercise, and not for real use. Indeed, in practical usage, the naive implementation in C (which does 2n comparisons) would also be faster than the divide-and-conquer solution because it accesses elements sequentially.

Comment: Typo: should be minmax(arr, mid+1, j), no?

Comment: Ummm, yes. Rather dumb of me to not realize that it's impossible to find the maximum in `log N` time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You will end up having a function call

```
largest(arr, 7,8)
```

Then your code

```
max1 = arr[i] if arr[i] > arr[j] else arr[j]
```

Will try to index arr[j] = arr[8] 
which is out bounds, as Python enumerates vectors from 0-7, not 1-8.

BTW, I don't think you have an O(log N) algorithm, as all elements must be scanned at least once to find the maximum element, leading to O(N).